# Assigning a selected value from a dropdown list to a php variable onchange, without pressing submit button in a html form?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have a html form and a dropdown list like this:

```
 <form name="form1" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">
  <div>     
    <span>Select Event</span> 
    <select id = "events" onchange="run()" class = "pass" style="width: 209px">
    <?php while($row = oci_fetch_array($curs)):?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row[0];?>"><?php echo $row[1];?></option>
    <? endwhile; ?>
    <input type="submit" name="action" value="New Event"> 
    </select>               
    TextBox1<br>
    <input type="text" id="srt" placeholder="get value on option select"><br>   
</div>
</form>
```

I can successfully show the values that I take from the database table. And after that I want to use the selected value for another query which needs this selected value simultaneously without pressing submit button.And my run function is like:

```
<script>
function run() {
    document.getElementById("srt").value = document.getElementById("events").value;
}
```

How can I assign this selected value to a php variable simultaneously?

```
    `
```

Comment: you can't. js runs on the client, php runs on the server. if you want the selected item to be "set" in php, you'll either have to submit the form, or use an ajax request.

Comment: What is the purpose of doing so ?

Comment: In the first dropdown list, user will select the city, and according to selected city id I will query the places in this city and in the second dropbox I want to show the places in this city.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible.
PHP script will never execute on onchange event.
Don't confuse it with JavaScript.
PHP scripts will only run on events like GET, POST, etc.